# items from menu_main not being shown as icon on actionBar, using sdk version 22

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to display the search icon on my action bar but it doesn't show up as icon even on setting showAsIcon to always.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search" android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_switch"
        android:title="@string/action_switch"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/web_hi_res_512"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_about" android:title="@string/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Are you extending `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` from the support library? If not, don't use the `app` namespace.

Comment: @ci_ i'm extending Activity class, do i replace it with android?

Comment: @ci_ thanks it worked. :) post answer so i cn accept it.

Comment: I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard "android" namespace when you're extending Activity, the "app" namespace is only used if you need the support library, i.e. extending AppCompatActivity or ActionBarActivity.